# Add order qty in mini cart

Tags: magento-1.9

how to add order qty in mini cart .[image: strong text]

This page [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code responsible for displaying the quantity (and the accompanying *OK* button) in original minicart template: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml`

```
<input
    id="qinput-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
    data-link="<?php echo $this->getAjaxUpdateUrl() ?>"
    data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
    data-cart-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getSku(); ?>"
    class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text" name=""
    value="<?php echo $this->getQty()?>"
    <?php if ($this->isOnCheckoutPage()) echo 'disabled'; ?>
/>

<button id="qbutton-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
    data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
    disabled="disabled"
    data-update
    data-cart-item-update
    class="button quantity-button">
    <?php echo $this->__('ok'); ?>
</button>
```

Copying a part or all of it to your minicart template would be a good starting point.